# What is the library for mathematical calculation in C?

Tags: c

How can i use square?
For example below calculation:

```
2^4=16
```

But when i do this the result is:6
Is there any library for this calculation without using multiplication?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c,a=2,b=4;
    c=a^b;
    printf("%d",c);
    return 0;
}
```

and How i can use radical in C?

Comment: [pow](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/)

Comment: use math.h, follow http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/math_h.htm for details

Comment: `pow` takes and returns `double`. If you use an inferior implementation with integers, you may be disappointed: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/04/06/Non-experts-need-accurate-floating-point-the-most

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` in C is the XOR operator.

Use [`pow()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pow.3.html) for what you want to achieve, like;

```
c = pow(a, b);
```

When linking your program you might need to reference the `math` library, by adding the linker option `-lm`.

---

Referring the update to your question: Use [`sqrt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sqrtl.3.html):

```
double  x = sqrt(4); /* Results in 2. */
```

Or simply use:

```
... = pow(4, 1./2.); /* Also results in 2. */
```

or

```
double y = pow(8, 1./3.); /* To also find 2. */
```

In general this formular applies:

[image: f]

Programmatical this can be done by:

```
/* Return n-th radical root of the m-th power to x. */
double nrt_mpow(doubel x, double m, double n)
{
  return pow(x, m/n);
}

/* Return n-th radical root of x. */
double nrt(double x, root n)
{
  return nrt_mpow(x, 1, n):
}
```

Or alternativly implemented as macros:

```
#define NRT_MPOW(x, m, n) pow((x), (m)/(n))
#define NRT(x, n) NRT_MPOW((x), 1., (n))
```

Comment: How can i use radical with other root:for example sqrt 8 with root of 3

Comment: `cbrt()` can be expected to be more accurate than `pow()` for computing the cubic root, even if `pow()` is correctly rounded, because `1./3.` is not 1/3.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: For a specific example, `cbrt(4)` is 1.5874010519681995834417875812505371868610382080078125, but the correctly rounded `pow(4, 1./3)` is 1.58740105196819936139718265621922910213470458984375. The former is the double nearest 4**(1/3).

Comment: What about a radical with root more than 3?

Comment: @invisible: Just follow the formular I posted: 4th root of 16 is `pow(16, 1./4.)` or `pow(16, 0.25)`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Added the missing dots.

Answer (score 4):

In C, `^`  is the XOR operator. `2 XOR 4` does indeed equal `6`.

You should include the `math.h` header file:

```
#include <math.h>

double pow( double base, double exp );

 ...
x = pow(2, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

The header to the math library is:

`#include <math.h>`

And instead of ^, C uses pow().

```
c = pow(a,b);
```

Comment: Nitpicking: `math.h` is the header to the libray. The libray is `libm.x.y.z`.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `^` is not power in C language. You should use `pow(a,b)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a header file `math.h`. You can use numerous mathematical function which are written there.

`pow()` function of `math.h` is the tool you want for exponentiation.